# How to disable click on empty rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I disable click/cursor on empty rows in `DataGridView`? I've alternating rows, one with data and another empty then row with data and then an empty row. I want to disable click on empty/null rows only.

I've improved my code thanks to breeze and partly got what i wanted to but this obviously applies to every cell. How can I implement this code so that ReadOnly Mode is true to only completely empty rows and not to those rows which has even a single cell containing data.

```
 private void dataGridView3_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var dataGridView = (sender as DataGridView);
        try
        {
            int col = e.ColumnIndex;
            int row = e.RowIndex;
            var cell = ((DataGridView)sender)[col, row];
            if (cell != null && cell.Value != "")
            {
                dataGridView.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView.Cursor = Cursors.No;
                dataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

    }
```

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Obligatory "what have you tried?" Please post your code.

Comment: Obligatory "what do you want to achieve?": you can't prevent the user from clicking, what difference do you want to achieve in your program how it handles the click?

Comment: I would assume that you want to essentially "ignore" the click event(s) when the sender is an empty row?

Comment: @Breeze Clicking on a cell opens another form which loads data of the cell, when an empty cell is clicked the new form is also empty of course and has no purpose.

Comment: does expanding `cell != null` to `cell != null && cell.value != ""` solve your problem?

Comment: @Breeze Wow it worked,thanks a ton..:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to not only check if the reference to the cell is empty but also if the value of the cell is an empty string. To do this you expand

```
if(cell != null)
```

to

```
if(cell != null && cell.Value != "")
```

The check if `cell` is `null` is not really neccessary but it does no harm and protects you against some errors that could happen in further development.

Comment: Thanks Breeze I got it

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there. This may need to be adjusted for your instance, and likely you should use "!=" to remove a few lines from the structure.

```
internal void AllRows_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;//Get Row that was clicked
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];//update to Row
    if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == ""){
        //Do Nothing
    }else{
        //Do Something
    }

}
```

Comment: What is "DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];" good for? And why do you check only Rows[1].Cells[1]?

Comment: @Nebr DataGridViewRow gives a direct line to the row, I should have added that into the statement, I'll edit it now.